# I showed an Alert and then I don't want to show another alert stack up it

Tags: swift, alert

I have a suggest update Alert when I opened my app. T written in **applicationDidBecomeActive**
Then i hide my app and reopen. I don't want to show another alert stack up

```
   for item in GlobalData.sharedInstance.linkContact?.socialLink?.forceUpdate ?? []{
            if item == currentVersionDouble {
                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Thông báo", message: "Chúng tôi đã phát hành một phiên bản mới hơn cho ứng dụng này. Bạn có muốn cập nhật không?", preferredStyle: .alert)
                let actionUpgrade = UIAlertAction(title: "Cập nhật", style: .default) { (_: UIAlertAction) in
                    if let requestUrlStore = URL(string: urlLink.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed) ?? "") {
                        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
                            UIApplication.shared.open(requestUrlStore, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
                        } else {
                        }
                    }
                }
                alert.addAction(actionUpgrade)
                UIApplication.getTopViewController()?.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                CFRunLoopWakeUp(CFRunLoopGetCurrent())
                break
            }
        }
```

And then i add func to applicationDidBecomeActive

```
 func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5) {
        ConfigApp.checkUpdate()
    }
}
```

I don't know how can I fix it

Comment: Where is this for loop located. 
I think it would be better to handle the display and dismissal of the `Alert` inside of a `ViewController` instance. 

Inside there you could just store a `boolean` property if the alert is already showing or not.

Is there no `rootViewController` which you could use for that?

Answer (score 0):

Add a boolean property to your class to keep track of whether the alert has been shown:

```
var alertShownBool = false
```

And then modify your checkUpdate() method to check if the alert has been shown before,& only show it if it hasn't

```
func checkUpdate() {
    guard !alertShownBool else { return }
    alertShownBool = true
}
```

Call checkUpdate() from applicationDidBecomeActive same as you are doing the same way.

From this change, alert will only be shown one time and the user open the app after the update become available. otherwise, the alert won't be shown again.